# GWT Anchor Text Setting

Tags: html, gwt

Here is my GWT Anchor code:

```
private final Anchor deviceSetupLinkAnchor = new Anchor(
            "Click here to Device Setup page", Window.Location.getProtocol()
                    + "//" + Window.Location.getHost()
                    + "/admin/tapeman.php");
```

What I want is only set "here" as the text to link the URL,don't want the whole text"Click here to Device Setup page" to be linked. How to do it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace "Click here to Device Setup page" with "here".

UPDATE:

Anchor is an inline widget unless you override the display property for 'a' elements in your CSS. So you can do, for example:

```
FlowPanel panel = new FlowPanel();
panel.add(new InlineLabel("Click "));
panel.add(deviceSetupLinkAnchor);
panel.add(new InlineLabel(" to Device Setup page"));
```

It's much easier in UiBinder where you can use simple HTML to do the same.

Comment: Are u sure you understand the question? Where to keep the remaining text??

Comment: I answered your question as you posted it :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I appreciate it. :) But do you think it's correct to add InlineLabel and Anchor? It may cause the error : The operator + is undefined for the argument type(s) InlineLabel, Anchor

Answer (score 0):

```
new HTML("Click <a href="/admin/tapeman.php">here</a> to Device Setup page");
```

or you could use an `HTMLPanel` and inject an `Anchor` where appropriate.